# How do I fix the SQL Error: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

When running the following snippet:

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR = '{"collection":[{"Type":"example_type","Value":"example_data"}]}';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Json) AS Options;
```

I received the following error

> Line 2: An error occurred during the current command (Done status 0). JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 1.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is a typographical error; it has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @ThomA I would not say that it is typographical error, it is type declaration error.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `JSON text is not properly formatted` error means that the JSON is formatted in an invalid state. However the above JSON is actually formatted correctly (
[If you don't believe me then feel free to check with a JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.org/)).

The issue here is that the SQL property is being declared as `NVARCHAR`. In SQL 2022 an unspecified NVARCHAR value is set to a single byte with a single character. In the above example it is being set to `.` for some reason. This is then causing an JSON Formatting error in the `OPENJSON` function because `.` is invalid Json.

Correcting the above with a declaration such as should resolve the issue.

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"collection":[{"Type":"example_type","Value":"example_data"}]}';
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@Json) AS Options;
```

Comment: 1) This is described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) and should affect not only SQL Server 2022 - _"When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n isn't specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30."_ 2) `PRINT @Json` gives me `{` (as expected) not `.`